# Optimizing Querydsl BooleanExpression queries

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I've created a class with static methods that return Querydsl BooleanExpressions so I can simply pass these expressions to the `findAll()` or `findOne()` methods in my Spring Data repositories, as well as reuse them throughout my application. Like here: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-five-querydsl/.

The issue that I'm having is that the BooleanExpression that's being returned from my methods is generating queries that seem to be sub-optimal (at least for my case).

Method that returns the BooleanExpression:

```
public static BooleanExpression byExternalIdAndProviderId(
     final String externalId, final Long providerId) {

  QEListing listing = QEListing.eListing;

  return listing.externalIds.any().externalId.equalsIgnoreCase(externalId)
        .and(listing.externalIds.any().provider.id.eq(providerId));
}
```

Query that is generated:

```
select elisting0_.id as id1_24_, 
    elisting0_.address1 as address2_24_, 
    elisting0_.address2 as address3_24_, 
    elisting0_.business_name as business4_24_, 
    elisting0_.city_id as city10_24_, 
    elisting0_.created_date as created5_24_, 
    elisting0_.latitude as latitude6_24_, 
    elisting0_.longitude as longitud7_24_, 
    elisting0_.master_ext_id as master11_24_, 
    elisting0_.modified_date as modified8_24_, 
    elisting0_.state_id as state12_24_, 
    elisting0_.zip as zip13_24_, 
    elisting0_.zip_4 as zip9_24_, 
    elisting0_1_.vanity_name as vanity1_34_, 
    elisting0_2_.account_id as account1_2_ 
from listings elisting0_ 
    left outer join vanity_names elisting0_1_ on elisting0_.id=elisting0_1_.listing_id 
    left outer join accounts_to_listings elisting0_2_ on elisting0_.id=elisting0_2_.listing_id 
where (
    exists (
        select 1 
        from external_ids eexternali1_ 
        where (
            eexternali1_.id in (
                select externalid2_.external_id 
                from listing_to_external_id externalid2_ 
                where elisting0_.id=externalid2_.listing_id)) 
                and lower(eexternali1_.external_id)='123456'
        )
    ) 
and (
    exists (
        select 1 
        from external_ids eexternali3_ 
        where (
            eexternali3_.id in (
                select externalid4_.external_id 
                from listing_to_external_id externalid4_ 
                where elisting0_.id=externalid4_.listing_id
            )
        ) 
        and eexternali3_.provider_id=1
    )
)
```

As opposed to something like this:

```
select elisting0_.id as id1_24_, 
    elisting0_.address1 as address2_24_, 
    elisting0_.address2 as address3_24_, 
    elisting0_.business_name as business4_24_, 
    elisting0_.city_id as city10_24_, 
    elisting0_.created_date as created5_24_, 
    elisting0_.latitude as latitude6_24_, 
    elisting0_.longitude as longitud7_24_, 
    elisting0_.master_ext_id as master11_24_, 
    elisting0_.modified_date as modified8_24_, 
    elisting0_.state_id as state12_24_, 
    elisting0_.zip as zip13_24_, 
    elisting0_.zip_4 as zip9_24_, 
    elisting0_1_.vanity_name as vanity1_34_, 
    elisting0_2_.account_id as account1_2_ 
from listings elisting0_ 
    left outer join vanity_names elisting0_1_ on elisting0_.id=elisting0_1_.listing_id 
    left outer join accounts_to_listings elisting0_2_ on elisting0_.id=elisting0_2_.listing_id 
    join listing_to_external_id a on elisting0_.id = a.listing_id
    join external_ids b on a.external_id = b.id
where lower(b.external_id) = '123456'
and b.provider_id = 1
```

Is there any way to generate a more optimal query, while still offering the re-usability of BooleanExpressions, and also using Spring Data's repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more optimal way, but joins can't be used, since they modify the result set. So if you find a way to optimize the any() subqueries in Querydsl, then please create a ticket in the GitHub issue tracker.

When the Querydsl usage is restricted to predicates, then there is no control over the joins.

Comment: From what I've found, the only way to use Querydsl with Spring Data is by passing predicates to a repository that extends `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>`. I really enjoy using Querydsl, but these queries are an issue for me. Is there any other way that you know of to use Spring Data with Querydsl other than with predicates as I have? When you say that joins modify the result set, do you mean that they change the columns returned, based on the fact that you are selecting all fields, even those in the joined tables?

Comment: Joins don't modify what columns are returned but how many rows are matched, which changes paging parameters such as limit and offset. The findAll methods are convenience methods for simple querying cases. The alternative is to use full Querydsl queries.

Comment: Right, so I would want to retrieve the entity manager that Spring Data uses and pass it in to a `new JPAQuery()` as in section 2.1.5, here: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.9.0/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e185. Am I following?

Comment: Correct. Although I think there might be convenience methods to create JPAQuery instances in some Spring Data repository support classes.